# How to detect stray tag delimiters in HTMLParser?

Tags: python, html

I am writing an html error detector to catch the most common errors in the html code my teaching assistants write for me. One very common error (since we are doing lots of math) is to write > instead of `&gt;` or < instead of `&lt;` (I need spaces to get StackOverflow to display named entity code instead of <>!) I tried catching this in the handle_data() method by detecting < or > chars, but it turns out that this has already turned `&gt;` into >, and `&lt;` into <, so it winds up also "catching" completely valid code.
Any ideas on how I can detect just the "raw" uses of < and >, and not the proper named entity uses?

Comment: Use the code formatting rules that stackoverflow provides. Either by indenting a code block or by using the inline code formatting (`).

Comment: Thanks Bilkokuya!

Answer (score 0):

If you're alright with reading directly from the file that needs debugging, simply do something along the lines of:

```
for line in file:
if all(char in line for char in '<>'):
    print(line) # do whatever you want done here
```

Comment: Well, that would catch actual tag delimiters, wouldn't it?I'd like to use HTMLParser, since it already recognizes and parses all of the actual tags for me.